# Chrome password field autocomplete=off not working

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, passwords

I tried so many things which were posted in other posts. BUT none worked. Finally i got my solution, which is as below.

```
<input type="text" id="password" required autocomplete=new-password"/>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

..

    $password = $('password');
    $password.on('input', function () {
        if($password.val()!="") {
        $(this).attr('type', 'password');
        } else {
        $(this).attr('type', 'text');
    }
    });

..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this even works. If you enter a single character and then clear it out, you go back to getting the suggestions. Worse even, now the suggestions show in plain text... Not great for your users that may have nosy peers

Comment: @SandeepShakya, I tried it, what I've commented above is the issue with this approach. Worth noting, I'm on Chrome 65